# implementing `comparable` and `comparator` interface: how to check whether int variables are well formed or not?

Tags: java, int, comparator, comparable

I'm learning the concept of implementing `comparable` and `comparator` interface to my own class and I  saw the statement below from Java tutorial oracle regarding to the best practice of implementing `comparable` and `comparator` interface:

> The constructor checks its arguments for null. This ensures that all
>   Name objects are well formed so that none of the other methods will
>   ever throw a NullPointerException.

I'm trying to create an `Employee` class with `int id, int salary, int age, String name` and `Date dateOfJoining` as instance variables. I know that primitive type such as int can't equal to null, but what should I do to check whether int variables are well formed or not?

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private int age;
    private Date dateOfJoining;


    //how to check whether int varaibles are well formed or not? 
    public Employee(int id, String name, int salary, int age, Date dateOfJoining){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.age = age;
        this.dateOfJoining = dateOfJoining;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        // to be implemented
    }
}
```

Comment: What would make an `int` variable malformed?

Comment: These would be 'business rules'. For a contextual example, only positive ages make sense (and even that range can be restricted). There is a whole lot of gray area on when/where to increase value restrictions.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in this context, maybe a negative int, a number other than int?

Comment: @dzjustinli3 An `int` like `-1` is still an `int`; without any context we don't know what would make an `int` invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial that you referred to is the [Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) tutorial. The particular statement referred to [the `Name` class that is given there as an example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/Name.java): If you created such a `Name` object where the `firstName` or the `lastName` object was `null`, then the `compareTo` method would throw a `NullPointerException`. This is prevented by checking the constructor arguments immediately.

More generally speaking, you should make sure that the `compareTo` method can **not** throw any exception.

As you already noticed, there is no way in which an `int` variable can be "malformed" in this sense. It can not be `null`, and no exception can be caused by comparing an `int` value to another.

However, there are several other points listed in the tutorial, and which you should take care of:

- you should implement `hashCode`
- you should implement `equals`
- you should make sure that your implementation of `compareTo` is **consistent with equals**, as described in the [`Comparable` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- If possible, make all your fields `final` so that the class is immutable

---

A hint: You can use the [`Integer#compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) method to compare int values conveniently.

---

A side note: Keep in mind that although an `int` value is always "well formed" in a **technical** sense, there certainly are **business** constraints that should be checked in the constructor. In your example, you'd likely want to insert additional sanity checks for some of the fields in the constructor:

```
public Employee(int id, String name, int salary, int age, Date dateOfJoining){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    if (salary <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "The salary should be positive, but is "+salary);
    }
    this.salary = salary;
    if (age <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "The age should be positive, but is "+salary);
    }
    this.age = age;
    this.dateOfJoining = Objects.requireNonNull(dateOfJoining);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found related [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

> The constructor checks its arguments for null. This ensures that all
>   Name objects are well formed so that none of the other methods will
>   ever throw a NullPointerException.

That `Name` object has two string member, they must be checked if they are null or not. Because if one them is null `lastName.compareTo(n.lastName);` this part will be cause a `NullPointerException`. You don't need to make a control like this for int members. because as you say, int variables can not be `null`.